# Ubuntu 14.04 wont boot after software update

Tags: update-manager

I downloaded an upgrade on my ubuntu,but did not restart my laptop,instead shut it directly.When i started my system and enter the system password, a black screen flashes and it comes back to password screen.I can't even access Guest session as it also occurs same problem.
How can i fix it without losing data?

Comment: It says " No command 'lscpi' found "

Comment: For command `lpsci | grep vga` it shows nothing,just executes the command

Comment: Please enter `lspci | grep vga`, sorry.

Comment: Again it just executes the command and doesn't show anything.Is it on any particular directory?

Comment: Are you sure you're typing it correctly? It should be `lspci`, not `lscpi` or `lpsci`. ***Did you make sure to log in in the terminal?***.

Comment: on executing `lspci | grep VGA` it gives the following output : `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller : Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)`

Comment: Try reinstalling Unity. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
`.

Comment: Still not getting it fixed, not even after executing the auto remove command. I'm getting the following output now : **sudo apt-get install reinstall Ubuntu-desktop **.               **Reading package lists.. Done**.  **Building dependency tree**    **Reading state information.. Done**.        **0 upgraded , 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 27 not upgraded.**.         **Need to get 0B/3758B of archives**.            **After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.**.          **WARNING : The following package cannot be authenticated!**.       **Ubuntu-desktop**.

Comment: **Install these packages without verification? [Y/N] y**.        **(Reading database ... 348501 files and directories currently installed. )**.      **Preparing to unpack .../ubuntu-desktop_1.325_amd64.deb ...**.        **Unpacking Ubuntu-desktop (1.325) over (1.325) ...**.       **Setting up Ubuntu-desktop (1.325)**

Comment: What can I do now..??

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update`, or `sudo apt-key update`?

Comment: Tried it .. But no help